# Capacity of a channel with random phase rotation

Tags: it.information-theory, coding-theory

Consider a wireless channel $h=e^{j\theta}$, where $\theta$ is a uniform random variable in $[0,2\pi]$ independent of the input messages and the independent of the noise. The channel randomly rotates the phase of the signal. For each new symbol (channel use), we have independent realization of $\theta$. Let average signal power be $S$ and noise power be $N$. Assuming that $\theta$ is **not known** at the transmitter and receiver, and remains unchanged during one symbol transmission, what is the capacity of this channel?

Note that we have an i.i.d. zero-mean complex Gaussian noise.

Comment: Is there any Gaussian noise? Without any Gaussian noise, the capacity seems to be $\infty$. Can you write the channel equation properly?

Comment: yes @Campello, we have i.i.d. Gaussian noise, as usual.

Comment: I still don't get it. For a general fading channel of the form  $y = h x + n$, the (ergodic) capacity is given by $E_h[log(1+|h|^2SNR)]$. Hence in your case |h| = 1, and you recover the capacity of the Gaussian channel..

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess $E_h[\log_2(1+|h|^2\mathrm{SNR})]$ is the ergodic capacity with transmitter and receiver side information. In my case, I do not know $\theta$, so I do not know the channel neither at the transmitter nor at the receiver.

Comment: It is actually the ergodic capacity with side information only at the receiver. I think for no side information, there are bounds (I found the paper "Capacity of fading channel with no side information", Taricco and Elia, Electronic Letters

Comment: Agree. Still, we do not have $\theta$ at the receiver, so that equation does not hold, I guess.

Comment: If the fading channel does not change the signal magnitude, it should not be zero. Simply, we can use symbols $\{+1/2,+3/2\}$, so these symbols are distinguishable at the receiver. The point is that, symbols with the same module are not distinguishable due to our fading.

Comment: ok u r right....... sounds like capacity is same as PAM

Answer (score 1):

$Y=e^{i\theta}X+W, \ \theta\sim U(0,2\pi),\ W\sim \mathcal{CN}(0, 1)$ with $\theta \perp W \perp X$ and input condition $E[|X|^2]\leq \mathsf{SNR}.$ Shannon's theorem gives 
$$C=\max_{X:E|X|^2\leq \mathsf{SNR}} I(X;Y).$$
Since the channel completely randomizes phase then $I(X;Y)=I(|X|^2;|Y|^2)$, and
$P_{\left. |Y|^2 \middle| |X|^2=r^2\right.}$ is a noncentral chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom and noncentrality $r^2$.

The maximizing distribution over $r$ was finally characterized in *The Capacity of Discrete-Time Memoryless Rayleigh-Fading Channels* by Abou-Faycal, Trott, and Shamai here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=923716

Surprisingly it is concentrated over a finite number of points.

But the number of points and their positions for a general SNR aren't known, so you have to numerically optimize the mutual information over these quantities.